# Clickable area around an image is too large

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to html and css coding and I am wondering if there is a way to make the clickable area around the bottom 4 images only apply to the size of the image.

Here's the website link: http://web.acd.ccac.edu/~amcma1b/

Yes, I know there is a lot of redundant code and I will eventually clean all of that mess up, but I'm searching for a way to fix my problem.

Css code here:

```html
body {
    background-color:#E6E6FA;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
p {
    text-indent: 10px;
 font-family:MySecondFont;
 padding: 10px;
 text-indent:15px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:120%;
 width:960px;
} 
h1 { 
display: block;
background-color:#85E0FF;  
     color:#4747A3;
  height:60px;
  width: 960px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:60px;
  font-family:MyFirstFont;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
 h2 {  
     color:#4747A3;
  height:50px;
  text-align:center;
} 



nav{
 display: block;
 width:960px;
 margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
 height: 40px;
 background:#85E0FF;
 text-align:center;
}

nav ul{
 
 text-align:center;
 margin:1px;
 padding:0;
 
}

nav ul li{
 list-style: none;
 float:left;
 margin: 0px 4px;
 
 
}

nav ul li a{
 
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 text-decoration:none;
 float: left; 
 padding: 10px 20px;
 color:black;
 width:100px;
 font-family:serif;
 font-style:italic; 
 font-weight:normal;
 transition-property:all;
 transition-duration:0.4s;
 transition-timing-function:linear;
 margin: 0 45px;
 
 
}

nav ul li a:hover{
 color: #85E0FF;
 background-color:white;
 border-radius:8px;
}

@font-face{
 font-family:MyFirstFont;
 src:url(Parisienne-Regular.ttf)
}
@font-face{
 font-family:MySecondFont;
 src:url(RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf)
}
 
#montreal img{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

li {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    margin-left: 2em;
 float:center;
}
```

and the html code here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Traveling To Montreal</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Topic:Traveling to Montreal">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML5,CSS3, Montreal, Traveling, Canada">
  <meta name="author" content="Alex McMahon">
  <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
<div class="headerBreak"></div>
  
<nav>
 <ul>
 
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>
 </ul>

</nav>
<br></br>
<div id="montreal">
<img src="montreal.png" alt="Montreal Skyline" align="middle";>
</div>
<br></br>
 <body>
  <h1> <strong>Traveling to Montreal From Pittsburgh</strong>!</h1>

  <h2><em>Student Website by Alex McMahon</em></h2>

  <DIV align="center">

 
  <p>Hello, on this website I will be discussing 4 different ways of traveling to Montreal from Pittsburgh!</font></p>
  <p>I will be discussing different ways in which to travel to the largest French speaking city in North America. I will be explaining the cost of each mode of transportation, along with the pros and cons of each mode of transportation. I will also be explaining what there is to
  do in the city while you are visiting and some of the more interesting places to check out whilst you are visiting!</font></p>
  
  
  <iframe width="700" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/poe2cLKw9ko" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <p> Click on an image below to learn more about your preferred way of traveling to Montreal!</p>
  <ol>
   
     <a href="plane.html"><li><img src="plane.png"></li></a>
    
     <a href="car.html"><li><img src="car.png"></li></a>

     <a href="bus.html"><li><img src="bus.png"></li></a>

     <a href="train.html"><li><img src="train.png"></li></a>
   
  </ol> 
<br></br>  
  <br></br>
<br></br>
  
 <footer>
<i><small> Copyright &copy; Alex McMahon<br>
<a href="mailto:imalintroller@gmail.com">imalintroller@gmail.com</a></small></i>
</footer>
  
 </body>

</html>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You're making the whole 'li' applicable to the href.
so just do as follow for the 4 images..

instead of this

```
<a href="plane.html"><li><img src="plane.png"></li></a>
```

do this

```
<li><a href="plane.html"><img src="plane.png"></a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Mark it as an answer if that's what ure looking for